# Drop rows in dataframe if length of the name columns <=1

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

**Please point out where i am doing wrong or a duplicate of this question**

I have 11 columns in my table, i am loading data from Ceph(AWS) bucket to Postgres and while doing that i have to filter the data with the below conditions before inserting data into Postgres

1. Drop the entire row if there is any empty/ Null values in any column
2. First name and last name should have more than a single letter. Ex : first name = A or last name = P, any record either first name or last name or both , entire record/row should be dropped
3. Zip code should be 5 digit or greater . Max 7 digit
4. First name and last name records should not have [Jr, Sr, I, II, etc] in it. or drop the entire record

i have managed to execute the first step (new to pandas) but i was blocked at the next step and i believe that it might also help me solve step3 if i find a solution for step2. While doing a quick research in google, I found that i might be complicating the process by using chunks and might have to use 'concat' to apply it for all chunks or may be i am wrong but i am dealing with huge amount of data and using chunks would help me load the data faster into Postgres.
I am going to paste my code here and mention what i tried, what was the output and what would be the expected output

what i tried:

```sql
columns = [
        'cust_last_nm',
        'cust_frst_nm',
        'cust_brth_dt',
        'cust_gendr_cd',
        'cust_postl_cd',
        'indiv_entpr_id',
        'TOKEN_1',
        'TOKEN_2',
        'TOKEN_3',
        'TOKEN_4',
        'TOKEN_KEY'
    ]
```

```py
def push_to_pg_weekly(key):
    vants = []
    print(key)
    key = _download_s3(key)
    how_many_files_pushed.append(True)
    s=sp.Popen(["wc", "-l", key], stdout=sp.PIPE)
    a, b = s.communicate()
    total_rows = int(a.split()[0])
    rows = 0
    data = pd.read_csv(key, sep="|", header=None, chunksize=100000)
    for chunk in data:
        rows += len(chunk)
        print("Processed rows: ", (float(rows)/total_rows)*100)
        chunk = chunk.dropna(axis=0)   #step-1 Drop the rows where at least one element is missing.
        index_names = chunk[(len(chunk[0]) <= 1) | (len(chunk[1]) <= 1)].index    #step2
        chunk.drop(index_names, axis=0) 
        chunk.to_csv("/tmp/sample.csv", sep="|", header=None, index=False)
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user        = os.environ.get("DATABASE_USER", “USERNAME”),
                                      password    = os.environ.get("DATABASE_PASS", “PASSWORD“),
                                      host        = os.environ.get("DATABASE_HOST", "cvlpsql.pgsql.com"),
                                      port        = 5432,
                                      dbname      = os.environ.get("DATABASE_NAME", "cvlpsql_db"),
                                      options     = "-c search_path=DATAVANT_O")
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.copy_from(open('/tmp/sample.csv'), "COVID1", sep='|')
        connection.commit()


def push_to_pg():
    paginator = CLIENT.get_paginator('list_objects')
    pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket)
    for page in pages:
        if "Contents" in page:
            for obj in page["Contents"]:
                if obj['Key'].startswith('test/covid-2020-11-10-175213') and (obj['Key'].endswith('.txt') or obj['Key'].endswith('.csv')):
                    push_to_pg_weekly(obj['Key'])
                    os.remove(obj['Key'])
    return
```

Data:

```
john|doe|1974-01-01|F|606.0|113955973|cC80fi6kHVjKRNgUnATuE8Nn5x/YyoTUdSDY3sUDis4=|2qalDHguJRO9gR66LZcRLSe2SSQSQAIcT9btvaqLnZk=|eLQ9vYAj0aUfMM9smdpXqIh7QRxLBh6wYl6iYkItz6g=|3ktelRCCKf1CHOVBUdaVbjqltxa70FF+9Lf9MNJ+HDU=|cigna_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
j|ab|1978-01-01|M|328.0|125135976|yjYaupdG9gdlje+2HdQB+FdEEj6Lh4+WekqEuB1DSvM=|j8VuTUKll7mywqsKrqBnomppGutsoJAR+2IoH/Tq0b8=|6qNP9ch57MlX912gXS7RMg7UfjtaP6by/cR68PbzNmQ=|R5DemSNrFvcevijrktwf3aixOShNU6j7wfahyKeUyzk=|cigna_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
j|j|1985-01-01|F|105.0|115144390|fn0r8nVzmDJUihnaQh1SXm1sLOIjzGsPDBskdX4/b+0=|Fh6facONoOiL9hCCA8Q1rtUp9n5h9VBhg2IaX9gjaKI=|NWtnZegpcpgcit2u063zQv3pcEhk4bpKHKFa9hW7LtU=|P3cVOUd6PyYN5tKezdMkVDI62aW8dv+bjIwKtAgX3OM=|cigna_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
jh|on|1989-01-01|M|381.0|133794239|PvCWdh+ucgi1WyP5Vr0E6ysTrTZ1gLTQIteXDxZbEJg=|7K3RsfC8ItQtrEQ+MdBGpx6neggYvBvR8nNDMOBTRtU=|nHsF/rJFM/O+HPevTj9cVYwrXS1ou+2/4FelEXTV0Ww=|Jw/nzI/Gu9s6QsgtxTZhTFFBXGLUv06vEewxQbhDyWk=|cigna_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
||1969-01-01|M|926.0|135112782|E2sboFz4Mk2aGIKhD4vm6J9Jt3ZSoSdLm+0PCdWsJto=|YSILMFS5sPPZZF/KFroEHV77z1bMeiL/f4FqF2kj4Xc=|tNjgnby5zDbfT2SLsCCwhNBxobSDcCp7ws0zYVme5w4=|kk25p0lrp2T54Z3B1HM3ZQN0RM63rjqvewrwW5VhYcI=|cigna_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
||1978-01-01|M|70.0|170737333|Q8NDJz563UrquOUUz0vD6Es05vIaAD/AfVOef4Mhj24=|k5Q02GVd0nJ6xMs1vHVM24MxV6tZ46HJNKoePcDsyoM=|C9cvHz5n+sDycUecioiWZW8USE6D2dli5gRzo4nOyvY=|z4eNSVNDAjiPU2Sw3VY+Ni1djO5fptl5FGQvfnBodr4=|cigna_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
||1996-01-01|M|840.0|91951973|Y4kmxp0qdZVCW5pJgQmvWCfc4URg9oFnv2DWGglfQKM=|RJfyDYJjwuZ1ZDjP+5PA5S2fLS6llFD51Lg+uJ84Tus=|+PXzrKt7O79FehSnL3Q8EjGmnyZVDUfdM4zzHk1ghOY=|gjyVKjunky2Aui3dxzmeLt0U6+vT39/uILMbEiT0co8=|cigna_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
||1960-01-01|M|180.0|64496569|80e1CgNJeO8oYQHlSn8zWYL4vVrHSPe9AnK2T2PrdII=|bJl7veT+4MlU4j2mhFpFyins0xeCFWeaA30JUzWsfqo=|0GuhUfbS4xCnCj2ms43wqmGFG5lCnfiIQdyti9moneM=|lq84jO9yhz8f9/DUM0ACVc/Rp+sKDvHznVjNnLOaRo4=|cigna_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
||1963-01-01|M|310.0|122732991|zEvHkd5AVT7hZFR3/13dR9KzN5WSulewY0pjTFEov2Y=|eGqNbLoeCN1GJyvgaa01w+z26OtmplcrAY2vxwOZ4Y4=|6q9DPLPK5PPAItZA/x253DvdAWA/r6zIi0dtIqPIu2g=|lOl11DhznPphGQOFz6YFJ8i28HID1T6Sg7B/Y7W1M3o=|cigna_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
||2001-01-01|F|650.0|43653178|vv/+KLdhHqUm13bWhpzBexwxgosXSIzgrxZIUwB7PDo=|78cJu1biJAlMddJT1yIzQAH1KCkyDoXiL1+Lo1I2jkw=|9/BM/hvqHYXgfmWehPP2JGGuB6lKmfu7uUsmCtpPyz8=|o/yP8bMzFl6KJ1cX+uFll1SrleCC+8BXmqBzyuGdtwM=|cigna_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
```

output - data inserted into postgresDB:

```
john|doe|1974-01-01|F|606.0|113955973|cC80fi6kHVjKRNgUnATuE8Nn5x/YyoTUdSDY3sUDis4=|2qalDHguJRO9gR66LZcRLSe2SSQSQAIcT9btvaqLnZk=|eLQ9vYAj0aUfMM9smdpXqIh7QRxLBh6wYl6iYkItz6g=|3ktelRCCKf1CHOVBUdaVbjqltxa70FF+9Lf9MNJ+HDU=|cigna_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
j|ab|1978-01-01|M|328.0|125135976|yjYaupdG9gdlje+2HdQB+FdEEj6Lh4+WekqEuB1DSvM=|j8VuTUKll7mywqsKrqBnomppGutsoJAR+2IoH/Tq0b8=|6qNP9ch57MlX912gXS7RMg7UfjtaP6by/cR68PbzNmQ=|R5DemSNrFvcevijrktwf3aixOShNU6j7wfahyKeUyzk=|cigna_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
j|j|1985-01-01|F|105.0|115144390|fn0r8nVzmDJUihnaQh1SXm1sLOIjzGsPDBskdX4/b+0=|Fh6facONoOiL9hCCA8Q1rtUp9n5h9VBhg2IaX9gjaKI=|NWtnZegpcpgcit2u063zQv3pcEhk4bpKHKFa9hW7LtU=|P3cVOUd6PyYN5tKezdMkVDI62aW8dv+bjIwKtAgX3OM=|cigna_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
jh|on|1989-01-01|M|381.0|133794239|PvCWdh+ucgi1WyP5Vr0E6ysTrTZ1gLTQIteXDxZbEJg=|7K3RsfC8ItQtrEQ+MdBGpx6neggYvBvR8nNDMOBTRtU=|nHsF/rJFM/O+HPevTj9cVYwrXS1ou+2/4FelEXTV0Ww=|Jw/nzI/Gu9s6QsgtxTZhTFFBXGLUv06vEewxQbhDyWk=|cigna_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
```

Expected Output:

```
john|doe|1974-01-01|F|606.0|113955973|cC80fi6kHVjKRNgUnATuE8Nn5x/YyoTUdSDY3sUDis4=|2qalDHguJRO9gR66LZcRLSe2SSQSQAIcT9btvaqLnZk=|eLQ9vYAj0aUfMM9smdpXqIh7QRxLBh6wYl6iYkItz6g=|3ktelRCCKf1CHOVBUdaVbjqltxa70FF+9Lf9MNJ+HDU=|cigna_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
jh|on|1989-01-01|M|381.0|133794239|PvCWdh+ucgi1WyP5Vr0E6ysTrTZ1gLTQIteXDxZbEJg=|7K3RsfC8ItQtrEQ+MdBGpx6neggYvBvR8nNDMOBTRtU=|nHsF/rJFM/O+HPevTj9cVYwrXS1ou+2/4FelEXTV0Ww=|Jw/nzI/Gu9s6QsgtxTZhTFFBXGLUv06vEewxQbhDyWk=|cigna_TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY
```

Any answers/comments will be very much appriciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest way to do operations like this on pandas is through numpy.where.

eg for String length:

```
data = data[np.where((data['cust_last_nm'].str.len()>1) & 
         (data['cust_frst_nm'].str.len()>1), True, False)]
```

Note: you can add postal code condition in same way.  by default in your data postal codes will read in as `floats`, so cast them to string first, and then set length limit:

```
## string length & postal code conditions together
data = data[np.where((data['cust_last_nm'].str.len()>1) & 
         (data['cust_frst_nm'].str.len()>1) &
         (data['cust_postl_cd'].astype('str').str.len()>4) &
         (data['cust_postl_cd'].astype('str').str.len()<8)
          , True, False)]
```

EDIT:

Since you working in chunks, change the `data` to `chunk` and put this inside your loop.  Also, since you don't import headers (`headers`=0, change column names to their index values.  And convert all values to strings before comparison, since otherwise NaN columns will be treated as floats eg:

```
chunk = chunk[np.where((chunk[0].astype('str').str.len()>1) & 
         (chunk[1].astype('str').str.len()>1) &
         (chunk[5].astype('str').str.len()>4) &
         (chunk[5].astype('str').str.len()<8), True, False)]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, FYI iam using python3.6,  however i got the below error: data = data[np.where((data['cust_last_nm'].str.len()>1) & (data['cust_frst_nm'].str.len()>1), True, False)]
TypeError: 'TextFileReader' object is not subscriptable.  i've also tried data[0], data[1], instead of using column names explicitly but got the same error, Thanks

Comment: this assumes that you have a pandas dataframe with columns ['cust_last_nm', 'cust_postl_cd'].  since you running it in chunks, you need to test it on a chunk inside a loop.

Comment: Worked! :) Actually it is supposed to be chunk[4] for the postal code right? i know the values for the postal_cd are weird though (606.0) may be its because i assigned the [character varying] datatype for it as instructed to me in postgres. Anyway it worked like a charm and i will accept this as an answer. One last question that i have is why there are True and False both listed in the chunk statement?

Comment: Good to know!  If you don't mind then upvoting the answer ;)    True and False are part of np.where clause, which basically has the structure, np.where(<what to check>, <what_to_put_if_match>, <what_to_put_if_not_match>).  I this case i built a column  that marked 'true' for when conditions matched and 'false' otherwise.  Then i pass this as index to the chunk, which does the filtering, keeping only true matches.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new column in the dataframe with a value for the length:

   `df['name_length'] = df.name.str.len()`
2. Index using the new column:

   `df = df[df.name_length > 1]`

Comment: Can you elaborate please, you mean to add a new column? i have two name columns to be filtered, so create two new columns? i might be clearly misunderstanding.

Comment: You are adding a column of name_length which will contain the length of the name present in that row. Then we are filtering that data frame based on the length i.e name_length columns should have a number greater than 1